# Gstreamer tsdemux reports "CONTINUITY: Mismatch packet" while receiving MPEG TS payload via UDP

Tags: udp, gstreamer, h.264, mpeg, gstreamer-1.0

My pipeline is the following (I recieving MPEG TS H264 video over RTP):

```
gst-launch-1.0 -v udpsrc address=127.0.0.1 port=1200 ! decodebin ! rtpvrawpay ! rtpbin ! udpsink host=127.0.0.1 port=2250
```

After start video transmits ok for a few seconds but then an error appears:

```
tsdemux.c:2413:gst_ts_demux_queue_data: CONTINUITY: Mismatch packet 2, stream 6
```

followed by the error:

```
libav gstavauddec.c:628:gst_ffmpegauddec_drain:<avdec_mp2float0> send packet failed, could not drain decoder
```

After that no more normal playback is possible and I need to restart pipeline again. What causes the error and how it can be fixed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turned out that the issue is in transmitter that does not send keyframes by some reason. This maybe also caused by UDP connection issues - it may sometimes miss packets.

Nevertheless VLC played the original stream fine, so this should have been achievable with gtsreamer as well (by playing stream with udp://@:1200 address).

I managed to solve the issue by increasing a buffer size up to 100 megabytes as below (I also supplied test to play video from the stream to check it works fine):

```
gst-launch-1.0 udpsrc address=127.0.0.1 port=1200 buffer-size=100000000 ! tsdemux parse-private-sections=TRUE ! h264parse ! avdec_h264 ! autovideosink sync=false
```

Comment: Thank you, adding the buffer solved my issues!